# How many different sets of k numbers {a1 , a2 , ....., ak } with integral ai ∈ {1, 2, 3,.....n} are thre satisfying 1 ≤ a1 ≤ a2 ≤ a3 ≤ ..... ≤ ak ≤ n.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

My attempt at it has been as follows:

first we take the case for all objects distinct and select k objects from the n objects in nCk ways, then we take the case of 2 objects being equal, and since these 2 would need to be consecutive there are n-1 such cases and the ways to select objects would be nCk-1 since we need to select one object less since two of them would be given the same object, and so on and so forth we go on till the case of all objects being equal which is only one case and we need to select objects in nC1 ways since only one object will be given to all. then we add these to get the final number of ways

but i am unable to find a way to add these or do anything after this, any help?

Comment: Looks like the [stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) can help.